# Solving a simple recurrance relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Question:

> Solve the following recurrance relation:
>
> $\ a_n = 3a_{n-1} $
>
> $\ a_1 = 4 $

But for the life of me, I can't understand why the answer is

> $\ 3^{n-1}a_1 $

My workings so far...

$\ a_n = 3a_{n-1} $

$\ = 9a_{n-2} = 3^2a_{n-2} $

$\ = 3^2(3a{n-3}) = 3^3a_{n-3} $

$\ = 3^3(3a_{n-4}) = 3^4a_{n-4} $

$\ \vdots $

$\ \therefore a_n = 3^{???}a_1 $

I just simply do not see how you can flip $\ n-1 $ and the exponent 1 and get $\ 3^{n-1}a_1 $, could someone please help to explain why?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Because $k = n - (n - k)$ (for any $k$, including $1$).

Comment: It is $$a_n=\frac{1}{2}$$ for all $n$

Comment: Start the other way. $a_2=3a_1$, $a_2=3a_2=3^2a_1$ and so on

Comment: To add on @ClaudeLeibovici's comment, you can formally prove it from that reasoning by induction. Prove it for the case $a_2$, and proceed for $a_{n + 1}$ given $a_n = 3^{n-1} \cdot 4$.

Answer (score 0):

We look for a solution in form of $a_n =\lambda ^n$

Plugging in the relation we get $$\lambda^ n =3\lambda^{n-1}$$ which results  in $\lambda=3$

Thus with $a_n =c3^ n$ and $a_1=4$ we get $$a_n =4(3^{n-1})$$